# how to set values on floating indexes in array

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing

I am unable to set values to float indexes in array like  `arr[4.2]=11;`  in C#. I also used indexers.

```
double[] arr=new double[10];

public double this[double index]
{    
     get
     {
         if (index > 0 && index <=10)  
         {    
             return arr[index]; //here is error 
         }
         else 
         { 
             return 0;
         }
     }  
     set
     {
         if (index > 0 && index <=10) 
         {   
             arr[index] = value;    //here is error
         }
         else 
         { 
             Console.WriteLine("can not set value"); 
         }
     }
}
```

There is an error that

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'

on `arr[index]`.

How can I set values on indexes like `arr[1.5]=10;` `arr[2.4]=20;` `arr[0.2]=30;`

Answer (score 0):

You can't index into an array by a non-integer. You would be better off using dictionary for that.

Floats generally make terrible indexes, as it's not only possible but indeed quite common for two similar-looking floats to compare as unequal.

For instance, in most environments (1/3 and 1-(2/3) will give two distinct results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Dictionary<double, int>`

```
var data = new Dictionary<double, int>();
data[1.5] = 10;
data[2.4] = 20;
data[0.2] = 30;
```

Be aware of floating point comparison issues. You can use `decimal` if you want to overcome the problem.

Comment: Just to confirm - you do understand that it is not practical recommendation as it only works for constant float values?

Answer (score 0):

You can NEVER has index as non integer at all.  just imagine if I would say you give me 1.57th element from array. It does not make any sense. If you want to have index as decimal or float you can use other datatypes like Dictionary or HashTable, but be aware of precision while comparing keys.